# Why do I get the error "The handle is invalid" when invoking GetThreadTimes?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

I need to get the CPU time of a worker thread. It seems I must use [GetThreadTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do this, since I'm targeting Windows XP and newer. According to the docs, Windows XP does not support [QueryThreadCycleTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here's the meat of a test program I wrote:

```
#include <windows.h>

UINT TestFunction(LPVOID pParam)
{
    TRACE("Thread Started!\n");
    Sleep(10000);
    TRACE("Thread about to terminate!\n");
    return 0;
}

...

CWinThread* thread = AfxBeginThread(TestFunction, NULL);

Sleep(500);

LPFILETIME creationTime = NULL;
LPFILETIME exitTime = NULL;
LPFILETIME kernelTime = NULL;
LPFILETIME userTime = NULL;

int result = GetThreadTimes(thread, creationTime, exitTime, kernelTime, userTime);

TRACE("Result: %d\n", result);

if(result != 0)
{
    TRACE("Got result!\n");
}
else
{
    //ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582(v=vs.85).aspx
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL
    );

    TRACE("Timing query failed with error %d: %s", dw, lpMsgBuf);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);

...
```

And I get the following debug output:

```
Thread Started!
Result: 0
Timing query failed with error 6: The handle is invalid.
```

Why is this? We know the thread is running because of the "Thread Started!" trace message. I've tried tweaking the sleep times until the thread has terminated. I still get the invalid handle error.

The test program is an MFC application built in Visual C++ 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `thread` is a `CWinThread *`. The parameter you pass to `GetThreadTimes` should be a `HANDLE`.

CWinThread has a cast operator to get the OS handle for the thread, so you should be able to use: `GetThreadTimes(*thread, ...)`.

There is one other problem though: you really need to change these:

```
LPFILETIME creationTime = NULL;
LPFILETIME exitTime = NULL;
LPFILETIME kernelTime = NULL;
LPFILETIME userTime = NULL;
```

To something like this:

```
FILETIME creationTime;
FILETIME exitTime;
FILETIME kernelTime;
FILETIME userTime;
```

Then, when you call the function, you pass the address of each, so your call looks like this:

```
GetThreadTimes(*thread, &creationTime, &exitTime, &kernelTime, &userTime);
```

Comment: Kinda mind blowing that the compiler even lets you pass `CWinThread*`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If memory serves, in VC++6 used `typedef void *HANDLE;`, so you could pass just about any pointer as a handle.